# How to increase a process capability inside kernel?

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel

I want to execute a piece of code in my kernel module with the capability of root, even if its called from a userland process with lower permission. I want to set the capability to CAP_SYS_ADMIN - execute a part - set the capability back to actual. Is it doable inside kernel? Please provide some example or reference of how is it done.

Answer (score 0):

Capabilities only apply to user processes. Code running within the kernel may *check* the capabilities of a user process before taking action, but it is not constrained by those capabilities.

Do not elevate the capabilities of a user process from the kernel. This is likely to be exploitable.

Comment: Its only for the purpose of learning. I want to create a file inside a directory which does not have write permission for anyone except ROOT. When i try that I get permission denied error. I wanted a work around that and stumbled upon Capabilities. Could you suggest some way to do it ?

Comment: The kernel should generally never interact with files directly (outside of the VFS layer, of course). There are a lot of ways that can go wrong. If the kernel needs to create files, it should do so through a userspace helper.

Comment: I am using filp_open from a stacked FS and trying to write directly to the file handle. The directory which I am accessing belongs to root. when i pass 'touch    <file1>' in that directory,  I need some way for the user normal user to create to be able to create file.

Comment: @avee137 sounds like you have an XY problem. I would suggest to submit a new question where you describe your objective & problem specifically.